# How to fix border color on mouse click

Tags: jquery, css, sass, colors

I have one color box, so when I am hovering on the box the border color is getting appear. Now I want to click on the box then the border color should be remain as it is. It should not get remove when you will remove the mouse from box.

My Scss:

```css
.fill-color1{
    background:$workspace-fill-color2;
    &:hover{
        border:2px solid $work-border-color2;
    }
}
```

```js
$(`.fill-color${i}`).click(function () {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
});
```

in the above code, after click the color is getting set but when I am removing the mouse from the box border is also getting remove.

Comment: On click add `border` not only `border-color` as 
`$(this).css({"border-color": "red", 
                    "border-width":"2px", 
                    "border-style":"solid"});`

Comment: Create a class which sets the border and on `.click()` add the class - that way you can easily reuse the class and change it, it's also then easier if you want to remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".Element").on("click",function(){
$(this).removeClass("Element").addClass("Elementfocus");
});
```

```css
div{
width:200px;
height:30px;
padding:10px;
}
.Element{
border:1px #E0E0E0 solid;
}
.Element:hover{
border:1px #e9e solid;
}
.Element:active{
border:2px blue solid;
}
.Elementfocus{
border:2px green solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Element">Hello!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a `border-color` to a box which have no `border`. It only have a `border` if you hover it.

Change this:

```
$(this).css('border-color', 'red');
```

to this:

```
$(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
```

Example here:

```js
$(`#test`).click(function() {
  $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
});
```

```css
#test:hover {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  Hover and click me!
</div>
```